# Imacros using eval find first digit in string and store in variable from that point forward

Tags: javascript, imacros

There is an address field that I'm trying to split out owner name and save only address forward. I have tried many things but can't split out and save from 9999 forward.
HERE is what extract HTM extracts:b 
`TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:Firstname<SP>R<SP>lastname9999<SP>E<SP>Shady<SP>Rd<SP>Unit<SP>99<SP>somewhere,AZ<SP>85000 EXTRACT=HTM`

Here is what I have so far but unable to solve the split problem.

```
SET Rev_addr EVAL("var w,x,y,z; w = \"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; y = w.split(' ');y;")
SET Sub_addr EVAL(" var x,y,z;  x = '{{Rev_addr}}'; y = x.split(',',3); z = y[2];z;")
```

This gets me to:
lastname
9999
I have tried many combos of split, slice, match etc. but nothing seems to do the trick.
Thanks

Comment: BTW: Configuration: Surface Pro 2, Win 10, Firefox 53, iMacros Standard Edition (x86) Version 11.0.246.4051.

Comment: Need to see the page or markup that you're extracting from.  there may be a class for address or lastname that you can specifically extract from that will allow you to split out the data properly but without seeing the source data, I can not help.